# Groovy parameters are not visible in shell part of a Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-2

I'm facing a problem in Groovy script wherein the variable is not accessible in shell script part.

script-1:

```
 def a=20;
 println ("a is: $a");
```

output-1:

```
a is: 20
```

script-2:

```
def a=20;
println ("a is: $a");
sh '''echo a is $a''';
```

Output-2:

> groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: Script1.sh() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String) values: [echo a is $a]
>   Possible solutions: use([Ljava.lang.Object;), is(java.lang.Object), run(), run(), any(), with(groovy.lang.Closure)
>       at Script1.run(Script1.groovy:3)

How can i get `$a = 20` in the shell part `sh`. In other words what operations are required to pass the variable $a in shell script part.

I'm writing this script in context of a Jenkins pipeline where i'm facing a problem that groovy variables are not visible in the shell part.

Answer (score 1):

this works:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Example') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // a is accessible globally in the Jenkinsfile
                    a = 20
                    // b is only accessible inside this script block
                    def b = 22
                    sh "echo a is $a"
                    sh "echo b is $b"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post { 
        always { 
            sh "echo a is $a"
        }
    }
}
```

You should use double quote for the shell statement and not triple single quote.

Comment: Thanks, I learned a thing or two, but are you sure about that second point? In a common Groovy script this is not the case (as shown by OP), but is that different within a Jenkins Pipeline script? (I understand they are... special). Or do you mean we *should* use braces? (that I understand)

Comment: @qlown you are right, second point is not true. Adjusted my answer.

Comment: @haschibaschi, Pls refer this link  https://groovyconsole.appspot.com/script/5088905221111808  I still get the same issue

Comment: @Yash you can't execute this code block in the groovy console. `sh` is a dsl word implemented by jenkins. This only runs on jenkins. I tested the script in a jenkins pipeline job and it worked.